# How to keep track of elements in a website with pagination using http request?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I've been working on a website (third party) with items displayed over pagination, each item has it's own ID set up in descending order (at the top of the page we have the latest ID and so on). What I'm aiming for is to keep track of newly added items so I can get the latest ID. I've actually done it but I don't think that this is the "appropriate" way of doing it.

ps: Assume that the website hasn't a public API.

Here's somewhat I did:

```
let param;
const axios = require('axios').default;
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

async function test() {
    await axios.get(sampleurl).then(res => {
        return res.data;
    }).then(text => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(text);
        if($('selectorOfLatestItem')){
            param = get_numbers($('selectorOfLatestItem').attr('href'));
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}  

test().then(() =>{
    xd.value = Math.floor(Math.random() * param) + 1;
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Note that "xd" is an input field which is taking a "random" number between 1 and param (the ID of the latest item).
get_numbers is a function that returns only the numbers of a given string.

Making request, parsing the DOM and so on are time consuming, is there another way of doing it? What I have in mind is as soon as the app is opening to make the request and get the latest ID and store it in a variable (maybe inside an external file or something) so I can use the value directly and then set an interval and make another request to check for newly added items and update the variable if there is any. Currently I'm making a request everytime a button is clicked so I can guarantee the latest ID will be included, consequently it has a delay to print out the number.

Scraping the website with pagination to get all the ID's is not an option (I think) since a lot of pages means a huge for loop to go through.

Comment: Can you pin-point the problem? There's a lot of detail in your explanation, a bit hard to follow.

Comment: Using http request I want to keep track of a list of items on a website and retrieve the newly added item. But I want to know if there's another way of doing it without having to constantly make requests and parse the DOM.

Comment: What adds items to that server? Where does it come from?

Comment: I mean an "external" website like ebay or amazon. Not correctly wording but I mean a server that isn't in my control like remote. Example: A new item is added on the smartphone section of ebay, I want to get the item data as soon as the item is added.

Comment: Ah well, you're webscraping. If that site doesn't provide an API for this, as you said- i do not see any way to be aware of new data, besides "polling" it(sending frequest requests). How come you cannot paginate the results(to fetch only last ones)? Can you explain?

Comment: I am getting the element just fine, but since I'm constantly making requests to get the latest item, if added, it makes the app I'm building to have a bit of delay on generating a random number. What I'm doing is, getting the latest item ID then randomizing a number between 1 and the item ID, so when a newly item is added I need to update the values and since I'm making requests everytime I want a number to be generate it has a delay outputting it. I just wanted to know if there's another way of doing so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209124/discussion-between-ryenra-and-i-brod).